# how to get only date in material ui datepicker react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use the [Material-UI pickers library](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker) to get the date
And I just want to get the date
like this **17/07/2021**

But I get both the date and the time like this
**Sat Jul 17 2021 12:21:00**

```
const [getDate, setGetDate] = useState(new Date());
<DatePicker
value={selectedDate}
format="MM/dd/yyyy"
minDate={new Date()}
onChange={handleDateChange}
label="Date"
size="small"
required
fullWidth
inputVariant="outlined"
animateYearScrolling
```

/>
[image]
Can you help me please?

Comment: It returns Date Object. You can format it using Date methods or using something like `momentjs`. Using `format` prop it shows date in format specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use formatter like [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) for your case, something like this:

```
import moment from "moment";

...

let date = getDate; // value from your state
let formattedDate = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

console.log(date) // before: Sat Jul 17 2021 12:21:00
console.log(formattedDate) // after: 17/07/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have changed from previous answer and now and object is returned and the date is inside $d,

I use daysjs so formatting is like this but can be adapted using the others also

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue)

return (    
  <DatePicker
    value={value}
    onChange={setValue}
  />
  <input type="hidden" name={name} value={dayjs(value.$d).format('YYYY-MM-DD')} />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={(event)=>{
                    console.log("date picker - ",event?.target?.value)
                    console.log("date picker event - ",event)
                    console.log("date picker event - ",event["$D"],event["$M"],event["$y"])
                  }}
```

You can print out the event object and see how the day, month, year etc data located. Here i've printed out the day and month and year.

[image: A picture of the event object format]